# How to indicate an element on a pop-up panel in UiPath?

Tags: automation, pycharm, uipath, uipath-studio

I'm doing an automation of **PyCharm** using **UiPath**. When I want to create a **python file** in this manner


*File > New > Python File*


After clicking "**New**", a pop-up panel appears on the screen in which the "**Python File**" option is lying.
Now the problem is I cannot successfully select an element (Python File) inside that panel. One thing to note is, I've already tried "**Click Image** activity". That unfortunately didn't work for me.

### 1. Is there any way to do this?

### 2. Is working with panels different from working with window?

Comment: Not sure what you really mean my friend. Maybe add some images? Please show the step with the new panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I think your bot is unable to click on "python file" option as given in the screenshot.
If the click activity is not working in this case, then please try the send hotkey activity and select arrow down. Once you are able to click File --> New, then automatically the cursor will be in the first option in the list which is file. Therefore the send hotkey (4 times arrow down) will take it to the python file option.

Again use the send hotkey activity to press enter. Your task is done.

Comment: Yes brother. This works and I already tried in this way. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Enjoy automation :-)

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could share a snip or screenshot of the window you're working on.

IF...you're getting a box to enter the file name (e.g. hello_world)...then I suggest you add the extension on the name like: "hello_world.py" and then click save or use a hotkey "enter".

I think you can even enter the whole directory or path where you want to save the file, such as "desktop\pythonFolder\hello_world.py"

Otherwise, maybe check on the menus if there's any key combinations that can do the trick, e.g. "Save CTRL + S" (so you can do ctrl S hotkey in UiPath to simulate pressing the keys).

Good luck!